# Flutter - Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._environment

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been running into some errors with a Flutter app that I'm trying to get running. This particular project was originally running on an older version of Flutter, but I've been updating it to work on 3.0+. When I try to run the app using the VSCode emulator, I see a loading bar on the top of the page, and then a white screen where I get this error. I've been looking around online and I have seen similar error Platform._OperatingSystem, but looking at those solutions, I haven't had any luck, and am feeling stuck on this at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._environment
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:266:49)
    at _Platform._environment (io_patch.dart:284:5)
    at get environment [as environment] (platform_impl.dart:83:17)
    at get environment [as environment] (platform.dart:168:59)
    at main$ (main.dart:33:25)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at main$ (main.dart:25:10)
    at web_entrypoint.dart:24:31
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:339:39)
    at initialization.dart:77:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1653:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:147:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:566:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```